# angularjs ng-disabled doesn't add disabled to button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input button that I want to set to disabled if a user selects a certain value from a select box:

Select menu:

```
<select id="jobstatus" name="jobstatus"  ng-model="associate.JobStatus" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Current</option>
        <option value="1">Former</option>
        <option value="2">Never worked there</option>
</select>
```

Input Button:

```
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right 
btn-lg btn-block" ng-disabled="{{associate.JobStatus === '2'}}" />
```

Now when I am viewing the source, when I do select option `2`, the input button element changes from value `ng-disabled="false"` to `ng-disabled="true"`  but the disabled attribute is not applied to the button.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use this

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right btn-lg btn-block" ng-disabled="associate.JobStatus == 2" />
```

Answer (score 28):

**Angular Doc** [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Curly braces means the notation {{ }} to bind expressions to elements is built-in Angular markup.

**Use:**

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="associate.JobStatus == 2" />
```

**Instead of:**

```
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="{{associate.JobStatus == 2}}" />
```

> same as for **ng-show / ng-hide / ng-if**, you can use the model
>   expression itself instead of {{}}

For Example:-

**Use:**

```
<div ng-show="someObject.showProperty">
```

**Instead of:**

```
<div ng-show="{{someObject.showProperty}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right 
btn-lg btn-block" ng-disabled="associate.JobStatus === '2'" />
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.