# AngularJS - ng-disabled true/false not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to disable or enable a button when the value of a variable changes. ng-disabled is viewing the change of the value but is not disabling the button if it is enabled.

Html:

```
 <form name="myForm">
      <input ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" ng-model="value" name="number" />
      Valid? {{myForm.number.$valid}}
      <button ng-disabled="{{!myForm.number.$valid}}"> Hello </button>
  </form>
```

Js:

```
 $scope.onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs ng-disabled doesn't add disabled to button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599064/angularjs-ng-disabled-doesnt-add-disabled-to-button)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to use interpolation(`{{}}`) inside `ng-disabled`:

```
<button ng-disabled="!myForm.number.$valid"> Hello </button>
```

Comment: @JosephOcasio NP. Glad to help :)

Comment: More broadly, you don't have to use interpolation for any ng-(...) attributes

Answer (score 2):

Remove the brackets within ng-disabled:

```
<button ng-disabled="!myForm.number.$valid"> Hello </button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The simplest things are always the hardest.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" ng-model="value" name="number" />
  Valid? {{myForm.number.$valid}}
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.number.$invalid"> Hello </button>
</form>
```