# ng-click not working in html table

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to use ng-click inside table but its not working, however outside the table its working fine.

Below is HTML

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
            <td>{{product.ID}}</td>
            <td>{{product.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{product.Section}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" name="name" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteProduct({{product.ID}});" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On click of `Delete` button `deleteProduct` method doesn't call.

Comment: Have you tried searching for ng-repeat creates child scope on the interweb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Problems :***

1. You are traversing through a collection/object named ***rules*** and getting single item as ***rule***. So you should access each single items properties with `rule.yourProperty`. How did product come here?
2. You don't need any double curly braces to for ng-click function parameters. Simply pass the property of the object. ng-click directive works this way.

***HTML :***

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">{{msg}}
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="rule in rules">
            <td>{{rule.ID}}</td>
            <td>{{rule.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{rule.Section}}</td>
            <td><input type="button" name="name" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteProduct(rule.ID)" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

***angular :***

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    var data = [
        {
            ID : "1",
            Name : "A1",
            Section : "A1"
        },
        {
            ID : "2",
            Name : "A2",
            Section : "A2"
        },
        {
            ID : "3",
            Name : "A3",
            Section : "A3"
        },
        {
            ID : "4",
            Name : "A4",
            Section : "A4"
        }
    ];

    $scope.rules = data;

    $scope.deleteProduct = function(id){
        alert(id);
        // delete your item here
    };
}]);
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/m10naocx/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
ng-click="deleteProduct(product.ID)"
```

Comment: Expressions {{ }} are used to bind application data to html.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599064/angularjs-ng-disabled-doesnt-add-disabled-to-button/29795830#29795830